# Use vue store in service-worker

Tags: vue.js, push-notification, vuex

I have `service-worker-push.js` in public folder and `registerServiceWorker.js` in src folder. When push notification is clicked I want to save that data in vue store but getting an error **Cannot use import statement outside a module**. Is there a way to save push notification data to vue store?

```
import store from "./../src/store";

self.addEventListener("notificationclick", e => {
  store.commit("pushNotificationData", e.notification.data);
});
```

File tree

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be

`import store from "../src/store/main.js"`

or simply

`import store from "store/main.js"`

It actually depends on which file this `import` statement is placed,
not clear for me in your question.